# replacing xml tags using replace function dont works

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml-parsing

```
<lb/>pis est) les oultragerent grandement les
          <lb/>appellans Trop diteulx, Breschedens,
          <lb/>Plaisans rousseaulx, Galliers, Chien-
```

i want to replace the  tag with 
 so that i can parse it easily should i use simple replace function of javascript or some regular expresions also!!!!

```
//open the document xml
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "GP.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml
  });
});

//pasre the document
function parseXml(xml)
{
  //find head and its text in the line breaks 
  $(xml).find("div").each(function()
  {
    $("#output").append($(this).replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
  });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$("#output").append($(this).replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
```

To this:

```
$("#output").append($(this).html().replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
```

With $(this) you get the object, but not the content of the object. For this you need the .html().

**EDIT:**

The $(this) referse to the $('#output') not the div.

```
$(xml).find("div").each(function() {
    var thistext = $(this);
    $("#output").append(thistext.text().replace(/lb/g, "br")); 
});
```

**EDIT2:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET", 
        url: "lp.xml", 
        dataType: "xml", 
        success: parseXml 
    }); 
}); 

//parse the document 
function parseXml(xml) { 
    //find head and its text in the line breaks  
    $(xml).find("div").each(function() { 
        var thistext = $(this); 
        alert(thistext.text());
        $("#output").append(thistext.text().replace(/lb/g, "br"));  
    });
}
```

Comment: but the problem still there i cant get replace my tag of lb even with$("#output").append($(this).html().replace(/lb/g, "br"));

Comment: this time i used replace(/^[lb]+$/, "br" but with no result

Comment: Try to alert the `this.html()` and let you show if there is ANY content. You're replace function was correct with `replace(/lb/g, "br");  `

Comment: Post more of the GP.xml (or part of it)

Comment: try this line: `$("#output").append(this.text().replace(/lb/g, "br");` (text() instead of html()). But when it works you'll have `<br rend="hyphen"/>`

Comment: Another question, the long text `<lb/><p rend="indent"> Car notez que <choice>....` is inside a `<div>`tag?

Comment: than use var thistext instead of this, or whatever you want

Comment: I made some tests now and when I use the code that I edited in my answer, I will get the text of the xml data, but without the tags. when I use html() instead of test(). I'll get an error message.

Comment: i tried this one
function parseXml(xml)
{
  //find head and its text in the line breaks 
 $(xml).find("p").each(function() {
     var thistext = $(this);
     $("#output").append(thistext.text().replace(/lb/g, "br")); 
 });
  }

Comment: What do you mean? You can store the retrieved text into an array?

Comment: When it's inside the div you can use thistext.find("placeName").text() inside the function to get the content of the tag "placeName".

Comment: with `thistext.find("placeName");` you should have an object, with this you can access the content with `.text()` and the attributes with `.attr("type");` and `.attr("key");` So just use this: `var placename = thistext.find("placeName");` and than `placename.attr("type");`

Comment: The comments on posts are not meant to be used as a live debug session.